# ECS deployment changes target group - how to maintain alarms that depend on target group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a workload running as an ECS service attached to a target group. Then I have an alarm monitoring that target group's instance count (HealthyHostCount). I'd like to implement blue/green deployments using 2 target groups, but it seems like because the alarm monitors a specific target group's value, it needs to be updated every deployment separately from the actual deployment.

This seems fragile and that there would be a better way to do this (e.g. after the deployment if we have a script that updates the alarm's target group, it could fail), but I can't see the better way. Is there an obviously easier solution?

Comment: I don't think there is a better way. Once b/g finishes, you have change the alarms "manually" using lambda function for instance.

Comment: @Marcin Yeah was worried about that  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of monitoring you have the desired number of healthy targets, monitor that you have no unhealthy ones.
Your ECS service will take care of managing your desired count, plus you might want to scale the service so UnHealthyHostCount is the better metric to alarm on, I think anyway.

Create one alarm for each target group as below.

These won't trigger between normal ECS blue/green deployments, only if there is a registered target failing health-checks. You need to tune the health-check settings on the target group and HealthCheckGracePeriodSeconds setting for the ECS service accordingly.

```
  BlueUnHealthyHostCountAlarm:
    Type: 'AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm'
    Properties:
      AlarmDescription: 'Alarms when there is any unhealthy target'
      Namespace: 'AWS/ApplicationELB'
      MetricName: UnHealthyHostCount
      Statistic: Maximum
      Period: 60
      EvaluationPeriods: 2
      ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanThreshold
      Threshold: 1
      AlarmActions:
      - Topic
      Dimensions:
      - Name: LoadBalancer
        Value: AlbFullName
      - Name: TargetGroup
        Value: BlueTargetGroup

  GreenUnHealthyHostCountAlarm:
    Type: 'AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm'
    Properties:
      AlarmDescription: 'Alarms when there is any unhealthy target'
      Namespace: 'AWS/ApplicationELB'
      MetricName: UnHealthyHostCount
      Statistic: Maximum
      Period: 60
      EvaluationPeriods: 2
      ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanThreshold
      Threshold: 1
      AlarmActions:
      - Topic
      Dimensions:
      - Name: LoadBalancer
        Value: AlbFullName
      - Name: TargetGroup
        Value: GreenTargetGroup
```

Comment: Ah! First time setting up B/G so might be an obvious mistake on my part, but in this case you're tracking the unhealthy hosts for both target groups, so as long as all deployments make use of the same 2 target groups, one of these alarms will flair up if there is a problem. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. An 'UnhealthyHost' is specifically a host failing it's health check, in a target group actively registered with the load balancer that should be receiving traffic, when a target that should serve traffic can not. I've used the above successfully for some time now.

Comment: Ah gotcha. Thanks! I'll give this a try